# Do Satelites travel in train like formation?

Tags: satellite, visible-light

This morning approx 5.30am i seen roughly 12 travelling in perfect formation approx 15cm apart , im  200km south of sydney Australia travelling from a north west direction

Comment: Yes.  see the duplicate question

Comment: "approx 15cm apart"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can. It depends on how the satellites are deployed from the launch vehicle.

Comment: There is also the "[A-train](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41780/12102)" which were not all deployed together but have none-the-less been maneuvered into a "train-like formation", though not "approx 15cm apart" :-)